# Excel unable to find the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[I am trying to fetch data from one excel to another, but vlookup is not working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSHBv.png)

[As you can see the data is present in the excel sheet. However, excel giving #NA error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqifz.png)

But When manually copy records from Copy of DSOM Customer summary docs.xlsx  then vlookup is working fine. I tried changing the text, style, format. vlookup is not working unless I manually copy data Copy of DSOM Customer summary docs file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWPcs.png)

Why the comparison of these two same strings is giving a false message? Trimmed the data, everything is identitical.

Comment: TRIM only removes the 7-bit ASCII space character (value 32).  I would verify that you don't have a nonbreaking space character (&nbsp;) that has a decimal value of 160, which TRIM will not remove.  Run a test by deleting TRIM(D2) and manually typing in the search value for cell D2.  Do the same for the value in your lookup sheet.

Comment: Tried it. Changed format, style but no luck.   But When manually copy records from Copy of DSOM Customer summary docs.xlsx then vlookup is working fine.

Comment: Your comparison image is the issue.  There is a non-printable character in one of those cells that is causing them not to be equal, and why your vlookup is failing.  Try using the CLEAN() function and check your results.